# using then and/or done in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

totally confused about `done`, `then` etc
getting some data using jquery ajax
want to prepend that data to a div and **then** trigger a click

```
$('#btnplus').on('click', async function(){
    let str = 'lorem';
    let data = await($.post('a_dict_pro.php', {fn: 'btn_plus', args: [str]}));
    console.log(data); // ok
    $('#atitles').prepend(data).done($('.atitle').eq(0).click());
});
```

data is prepended but `atitle.click` shows this error:

`$(...).prepend(...).done is not a function`

pls, help

Comment: Use `await` *or* use `.done()` but not both on the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.done` can only be called on a [deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). But `.prepend` does not involve anything asynchronous; it just gives you a plain jQuery collection in return.

All the asynchronous logic has been taken care of by the `await` above. Everything below that is synchronous, so just click the `.atitle` synchronously:

```
$('#btnplus').on('click', async function(){
    let str = 'lorem';
    let data = await($.post('a_dict_pro.php', {fn: 'btn_plus', args: [str]}));
    $('#atitles').prepend(data);
    $('.atitle').eq(0).click();
});
```

Comment: are you sure that `click` will not be the first and `prepend` the second? Because `prepend` takes some time to be finished

Comment: No, `.prepend`, when called, should insert the data instantly. There should not be any delay unless you're using something that modifies its default behavior. It's just like `appendChild` or `insertBefore`

Comment: there is a lot of data, I see on screen - it takes about one second. And I tried - `$('.atitle').eq(0)` is inside prepended data and it is not clicked

Comment: Even with huge amounts of data, it will still be inserted into the DOM synchronously, before the next line of JS runs. It may take the browser some time to process it, but it is still guaranteed to be there before any more JS runs. Double-check that the render result really does contain a `.atitle`.